# how to change the coordinate system of SDL for c++

Tags: c++, sdl

i want to draw a point with -ve coordinate sytem as 
SDL_RenderDrawPoint( renderer , -20 , -40 );

but as SDL co-ordinate sytem just allow me the first quadrant coordinate as it is (0,0 ) at the top left corner and goes to bottom right corner ( width, height ) , so show i suppose to perform some drawing with -ve co-ordinate system.

Comment: Why not use `width/2` and `height/2` as your origin?

Comment: I am using a algo that work with -ve coordinate , if use this i may have to change my algo too

Comment: Thanks David , when i try your idea its work , without any trouble so thank you and sometime very simple things are the answer of our problem but we are looking for complex one follishly.